# Ensuring RavenDB 3.0 FileSystem Synchronization Before Action

Tags: c#, ravendb

Here is the setup:

- There are 2 Servers : one at the client site and one on another server
- The connection between the two of them is not always on.
- I have to have code that replicates the functionality from the Server UI: FileSystem > Status > "Sync Now"
- I have to be able to watch the process to ensure that it completes without conflicts before moving I move on the next step.

Can anyone point me to the proper classes in the Raven Client Library to do this? Examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
 DestinationSyncResult[] syncResults = await store.AsyncFilesCommands.Synchronization.SynchronizeAsync();
```

This will force your server to push all changes to destinations and return all the details about processed files and errors if happened any. Investigate also more methods exposed by IAsyncFilesSynchronizationCommands:

```
store.AsyncFilesCommands.Synchronization.XXXXX
```

You can also use the Changes API mechanism to be notified about server activity. It works the same way like for RavenDB databases. For example:

```
store.Changes().Where(x => x.Direction == SynchronizationDirection.Outgoing).ForSynchronization().Subscribe(x => { });
```